# Call a method inside onReceive

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

Not able to call cameraImage() method inside onReceive().

```
   private BroadcastReceiver dataReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent i) {
        Log.e("Data", "Service Recieved");

        responseString = i.getStringExtra(DataRequest.EXTENDED_DATA_STATUS);
        textView.setText(responseString);

        if (Float.parseFloat(responseString) < 100) {
            cameraImage();
        }

    }
};
```

cameraImage() is written in the same activity

```
public void cameraImage(){
    camera.takePicture(null, null, jpegCallback);
}
```

Comment: which error do  you get?

Comment: @user5599807 It did not help getting the errror.    java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=com.tecknik.tecknik.transaction_done flg=0x10 (has extras) } in com.teckniktecknik.CameraActivity$2@4358a7c8                                      Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: takePicture failed